# Cypher nested collect query does not aggregate correctly

Tags: neo4j, cypher, collect

I want to perform this query

```
MATCH (p:Person)-->(s:Startup)
WITH DISTINCT p
MATCH (p)-->(s:Startup)-->(m:Market)
WITH DISTINCT p, s, m, COLLECT(m) as markets
ORDER BY id(s)
RETURN DISTINCT p, COUNT(DISTINCT s) as inv, 
                COLLECT({id: id(s), markets: markets}) as startups, 
                count (m) as mctotal
ORDER BY inv DESC
LIMIT 10
```

but I can't figure out why it does not aggregate correctly startups with their markets.
This is the result of my query:

```
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
|  p  | inv | startups   | mctotal |
+-----+-----+------------+---------+
|  p  |  11 | id: 1      |    7    |
|     |     | markets: 1 |         |
|     |     |            |         |
|     |     | id: 1      |         |
|     |     | markets: 2 |         |
|     |     |            |         |
|     |     | id: 2      |         |
|     |     | markets: 3 |         |
|     |     |            |         |
|     |     | id: 2      |         |
|     |     | markets: 4 |         |
```

... and so on.

The result that I want to obtain is the following:

```
+-----+-----+---------------+---------+
|  p  | inv | startups      | mctotal |
+-----+-----+---------------+---------+
|  p  |  11 | id: 1         |    7    |
|     |     | markets:[1,2] |         |
|     |     |               |         |
|     |     | id: 2         |         |
|     |     | markets:[3,4] |         |
```

I hope it's clear what I'm asking for.

Comment: don't use distinct with aggregation it doesn't make sense

Comment: thank you, I know but with this query, if I don't use DISTINCT it counts all the results and perfoms fake count

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. don't use distinct with aggregation
2. don't aggregate the same value that you return as simple value **(this is your main issue)**
3. don't match twice

Here is a variant that should work better, you didn't share your sample graph, so I couldn't try it

```
 MATCH (p)-->(s:Startup)-->(m:Market)
 WITH p, s, COLLECT(m) as markets, count(m) as mcount
 ORDER BY id(s)
 RETURN p, COUNT(DISTINCT s) as inv, 
           COLLECT({id: id(s), markets: markets}) as startups, 
           sum(mcount) as mctotal
 ORDER BY inv DESC
 LIMIT 10
```

Comment: you're right, sorry if I didn't catch that immediately, this is definitely the solution of my problem. thank you very much